# What does "overflow" do for this <ul> tag?

Tags: html, css

I was creating this header menu using `<ul>` and I wanted to stretch it to all top of the page. I first used `width:100%` but it didn't work.Then I saw a similar example somewhere , it had used `overflow:hidden` so when I used that it streched the list to the end.I wanted to know what does `overflow` do in here and why `width:100%` can not do the similar action?

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: black;
}
li {
 
 background-color: black;
 color: red;
 
 float: left;
}
li a{
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 
}
li a:hover{
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css"> 
 </head>
     <body>
 <ul>
   <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a></li>
   <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.Amazon.com">Amazon</a></li>
   
   </ul>
 
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

using `overflow` makes element stretch to match its children when they have set `float` property - it's basically one of ways to implement *clearfix*

Comment: I had no idea it stretches the element.. Everyday's a schoolday!

Comment: magic of css :) useful when you don't want to play with `::after` and it's even cross-browser!

Answer (score 1):

Float property in li affect the parent ul width 100%. so It not worked. 
Try this below code.

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: black;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
li {
 background-color: black;
 color: red;
 width:33.3333%;
 float: left;
    
}
li a{
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 20px;
}
li:hover{
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css"> 
 </head>
     <body>
 <ul>
   <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a></li>
   <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.Amazon.com">Amazon</a></li>
   
   </ul>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think OP is looking for some solution, it's more an information request..

Comment: Maybe you don't need to remove.

Comment: it was useful tip,tnx